# How can I access a variable from a function without calling the function itself

Tags: javascript

I have a function in module.exports but I want to get one of the functions variable without actually running it, I'm not too sure how to explain so I'll just show the code.
First file:

```
    module.exports = {
        1: 'bla bla',
        2: 'not important',
        function () { 
            var D = 4;
            //...
        },
     }
```

Second file:

```
const number = require('./file1.js');

var sum = 4 + //now I want to access the var D from the function in 
module.exports
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define it as object field  :

```
    module.exports = {
        1: 'bla bla',
        2: 'not important',
        D:4,
        funcName: function () { 
           //here you could get access to the field and change it
        },
     }
```

then use it like :

```
const number = require('./file1.js');
var sum = 4 + number.D
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `D` is local to the function, which means you can't see or change it from the outside. This roughly corresponds to having a private field in an object.